# Does `eval` apply the shell to the redirection part of the following command?

Tags: bash, eval

When use `eval` on a command, does `eval` apply the shell twice to the redirection part of the command?

Suppose the filename in the redirection contains a whitespace, if `eval` applies all the steps of parsing, shell expansions and word splitting and other steps to it more than once, the filename will be split into two words during the word splitting step in the second round.

Does the following example imply that `eval` doesn't apply the shell twice to the redirection part of the following command, so the filename is not split into two words?

```
$ filename="my file"
$ eval "cat" < "$filename"
hi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you provide, the only thing `eval` is getting is `cat`, the redirection is happening outside the `eval` and the file is being provided as stdin for the `eval "cat"` command.

One variation is to quote the whole command, including the redirection, using single quotes:

```
$ eval 'cat < "$filename"'
hi
```

Now `eval` is getting the whole string, including the redirection and the variable name, so it's doing variable expansion and the needed quoting for the filename with spaces. This would still work.

Another option is using double quotes for the string:

```
$ eval "cat < '$filename'"
hi
```

Now the variable is expanded by the shell, but this still works since the quotes inside it keep the filename together. (Note that this would break if the filename contains an apostrophe, though.)

What would *not" work is this:

```
$ eval "cat" "<" "$filename"
```

This is similar to your example, but with the `<` quoted, the redirection will not be executed by the external shell. `eval` will then put together the arguments, and the resulting command will be:

```
cat < my file
```

Which will not work as expected, since the quotes around `my file` are now gone...

Answer (score 1):

The way `eval` works is by constructing the arguments together as one shell command to run. Since your variable `filename` **is quoted, it will not undergo word-splitting** when *this* command is constructed to run.

The same may not apply for a case of your filename with spaces and an unquoted expansion will cause an error. For e.g.

```
filname=my\ file
echo "dude" > my\ file
eval cat < $filename
bash: $filename: ambiguous redirect
```

Notice the word-splitting done here and `cat` receives an incorrect filename for input redirection causing the error.

Also notice that, if not for the re-direction when using `cat`, if used on the file directly, `eval` will make `cat` open two files in this case, i.e.

```
eval cat $filename
```

will translate into running

```
cat my file
```

E.g. if you have file named `file` in your current directory, it will display its contents and show file not present for the file named `my` on error stream.

```
filename=my\ file
echo "foo" > file
```

We are making the file `my` to be not present

```
eval cat $filename 2>&1
cat: my: No such file or directory
foo
```